# Nokia netbook won't boot after install

Tags: installation, nokia

I installed ubuntu 12.04 onto my nokia 3g netbook, to replace the windows 7 starter that I had.

Once the install finished it prompted me to restart my computer. I did this, but rather than booting up the screen just goes black.

I managed to boot up from the USB again and trying a fresh install overriding the previous one, but I have the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this.Pin the USB to netbook and try to start it.See what happens.I think the installer put the boot loader on USB.Post your result here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried this. It booted up the installer again. But the screen was a mess. Only the top half of the screen was being used (the bottom was just black) and if i moved the mouse weird things happened. I have no idea what has gone wrong.

Comment: Also thought I should mention that after the install (before I restarted) Ubuntu worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a working Ubuntu system before rebooting, it should be something to do with grub installation, booting, MBR, etc.
As a possible solution for such problems, you might give a try to rescatux:
[www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/)